# Aligning the \text in formula

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, lyx

I have, let's say, 5 of the equations spread throughout the document and I want them to be aligned similarly. The equation consist of two parts -- the formula itself and short descriptions (let's say boundaries). Obviously, there can be a lot of text (plus figures between) between any two equations. Can all the equations (and their parts) be aligned in the same way? This is an example:

```
\[
G=G_{I}=\begin{cases}
\cfrac{K_{I}^{2}}{E} & \text{plane stress}\\
\cfrac{(1-\nu^{2})K_{I}^{2}}{E} & \text{plane strain}
\end{cases}
\]
```

[image: img]

One equations with two lines, short comment about them, the part on the right aligned in the same way. However, I can't find a solution to align these throughtout the document (i.e., in multiple equations). It should look something like this

[image: img]

but the boundaries in this case are misaligned and the `&` operator can't be used. Is there a feature I'm missing or a workaround?

Comment: `&` should be used within `align`. For one line equation you can simply use `\quad` to insert some horizontal space.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. It doesn't make sense to use alignment in one-lined math expressions; simply use, say, `\qquad` to add some horizontal space.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The coding you suggest is rather non-standard.  Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Note that you are missing `}`, but this is not the reason for the problem.

Comment: For future questions: It's a good idea to always post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) when asking (or answering) a question.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent Something\dots
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  K_{C} &= \sqrt{EG_{c}} &\qquad &\text{(plane stress)}\\
  \intertext{further description of the equation}
  K_{c} &= \sqrt{\frac{EG_{c}}{1-\nu^{2}}} &&\text{(plane strain)}
\end{alignat*}
Something\dots

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: That´s basically what I want but when used for multiple single-line formulas it does this
![link](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2w6ummr.jpg)

and I would really like the two notes next to equations to be aligned.

Comment: @VáclavŠefl See updated answer.

Comment: On the other hand - this is not very practical if the "further description of the equeations" should be a longer text, possibly including figures. If it is treated as intertext I´d lose a whole bunch of formatting capabilities, is that right? 

So to rephrase my original question - I have, let´s say 5 of the equations shown above, spread throughout the document and I want them to be aligned similarly. (like each of those above). Can this be done without them being in the same group?

Comment: @VáclavŠefl -- you've just expressed an important criterion in your comment.  it would be much more visible added to the question; you should be able to edit the question to include it.

Comment: @VáclavŠefl Next time, please include the entire question the first time you post it! (Now you've asked for something additional twice...)

Comment: Sorry, Im a newbie around here...

Comment: @VáclavŠefl I don't think you can align equations in different groups. Maybe someone with (far) more LaTeX knowledge can elaborate on this.

Comment: What I tend to do in these cases is to write a custom table header with fixed widths and reuse that through the document, then the lining up is consistent (but obviously less flexible).

Comment: @Thruston That was my thought, too, but if the equations are spread throughout the document, how would you then go about doing it?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg either just copy the halign headers (if I know I'm not going to change it) or define a one-shot macro for them.

Comment: @VáclavŠefl If formulas are far away from each other, keeping the alignment has no purpose. It might even look quite odd.

Comment: @egreg "far" is pretty relative in this case, two equations could be separated by a page or just 1-2 lines of text...

Comment: @VáclavŠefl Don't try preserving alignment then.