# How insert a text on middle right of eqnarray

Tags: text, eqnarray

I want to write the text (1st case) on the middle right of this two equation, any idea for this? Thank you.

```latex
      \begin{eqnarray*}
        % \nonumber % Remove numbering (before each equation)
          \tau_{h}^{*}(x^{*}) &=& \frac{-(1 - \lambda V^{*\infty}\tau_{h,in}^{*})x^{*} + (1 + V^{*\infty}\tau_{h,in}^{*})}{(1 + \lambda)V^{*\infty}} \\
          \tau_{c}^{*}(x^{*}) &=& (\frac{1}{1 + \gamma})\{1 - \gamma \tau_{h,in}^{*} - \frac{\gamma}{(1 + \lambda) V^{*\infty}}\} x^{*} + (\frac{1}{1 + \lambda})(\frac{1}{V^{*\infty}} + \tau_{h,in}^{*}) \qquad   \text{(First case)}
        \end{eqnarray*}
```

[image]

Comment: Can some of these answers may be the solution? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402902/independent-text-in-between-aligned-eqnarray

Comment: @Sango - I wouldn't say that the answers in the link you provided solve the OP's question. The OP wants to place a string -- here: "First case" -- to the *right* of the two equations. In contrast, the main answer in your linked posting shows how to place text *left-aligned* and *between* the rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `eqnarray` or `eqnarray*`. See the posting [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001) for an in-depth discussion of this issue.

Use one of the multi-line equation environments of the `amsmath` package instead. For the case at hand, I suggest you employ a `split` environment. The `amsmath` package provides the instruction `\tag`; it would appear to meet your typesetting requirement perfectly.

While you're at it, you may also want to increase the sizes of the round parentheses and curly braces in the second row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' env. and '\tag' macro
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{split}
\tau_{h}^{*}(x^{*}) 
&= \frac{-(1 - \lambda V^{*\infty}\tau_{h,in}^{*})x^{*} 
  + (1 + V^{*\infty}\tau_{h,in}^{*})}{(1 + \lambda)V^{*\infty}} \\
\tau_{c}^{*}(x^{*}) 
&= \Bigl(\frac{1}{1 + \gamma}\Bigr)
   \Bigl\{1 - \gamma \tau_{h,in}^{*} 
      - \frac{\gamma}{(1 + \lambda) V^{*\infty}}\Bigr\} x^{*} 
+ \Bigl(\frac{1}{1 + \lambda}\Bigr)
  \Bigl(\frac{1}{V^{*\infty}} + \tau_{h,in}^{*}\Bigr) 
\end{split}
\tag{First case}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't want parentheses around "First case", use `\tag*` instead of `\tag`.

Answer (score 5):

Here are three possibilities, one is based on the `empheq` package, which loads `mathtools`, which loads `amsmath`. I also improved a bit the look of the equations, removing unnecessary parentheses.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{empheq, amssymb}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{2}
        % \nonumber % Remove numbering (before each equation)
          \tau_{h}^{*}(x^{*}) &=\frac{-(1 - \lambda V^{*\infty}\tau_{h,in}^{*})x^{*} + (1 + V^{*\infty}\tau_{h,in}^{*})}{(1 + \lambda)V^{*\infty}} & & \\
    \ArrowBetweenLines*[\text{First case}]
          \tau_{c}^{*}(x^{*}) &=\frac{1}{1 + \gamma}\Bigl(1 - \gamma \tau_{h,in}^{*} - \frac{\gamma}{(1 + \lambda) V^{*\infty}}\Bigr) x^{*} + \frac{1}{1 + \lambda} \Bigl(\frac{1}{V^{*\infty}} + \tau_{h,in}^{*}\Bigr) & &
        \end{alignat*}
    \bigskip

    \begin{empheq}[right=\text{\quad First case}]{align*}
          \tau_{h}^{*}(x^{*}) &=\frac{-(1 - \lambda V^{*\infty}\tau_{h,in}^{*})x^{*} + (1 + V^{*\infty}\tau_{h,in}^{*})}{(1 + \lambda)V^{*\infty}} \\[1ex]
          \tau_{c}^{*}(x^{*}) &=\frac{1}{1 + \gamma}\Bigl(1 - \gamma \tau_{h,in}^{*} - \frac{\gamma}{(1 + \lambda) V^{*\infty}}\Bigr) x^{*} + \frac{1}{1 + \lambda} \Bigl(\frac{1}{V^{*\infty}} + \tau_{h,in}^{*}\Bigr)
    \end{empheq}
    \bigskip

    \begin{equation}\tag*{First case}
      \begin{aligned}
          \tau_{h}^{*}(x^{*}) &=\frac{-(1 - \lambda V^{*\infty}\tau_{h,in}^{*})x^{*} + (1 + V^{*\infty}\tau_{h,in}^{*})}{(1 + \lambda)V^{*\infty}} \\[1ex]
          \tau_{c}^{*}(x^{*}) &=\frac{1}{1 + \gamma}\Bigl(1 - \gamma \tau_{h,in}^{*} - \frac{\gamma}{(1 + \lambda) V^{*\infty}}\Bigr) x^{*} + \frac{1}{1 + \lambda} \Bigl(\frac{1}{V^{*\infty}} + \tau_{h,in}^{*}\Bigr)
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/217524/197451-- is this your requirement

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent Something\dots
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  K_{C} &= \sqrt{EG_{c}} &\qquad &\text{(plane stress)}\\
  \intertext{further description of the equation}
  K_{c} &= \sqrt{\frac{EG_{c}}{1-\nu^{2}}} &&\text{(plane strain)}
\end{alignat*}
Something\dots

\end{document}
```

### OR

another solution with the help of manual `raisebox`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:distrib}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
n_c    &= \max[N \cdot z_{\max} \cdot x, 2 \cdot n_{\min}]
&\quad&\raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
    where $x\sim U([0,1])$%
} \\
n_{co} &= \min[\max[n_c \cdot x, n_{\min}], n_c - n_{\min}] \\
n_{cp} &= n_c - n_{co} \\
n_f    &= N - n_c
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

from -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391034/197451

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I thought the OP's objective was to place the text snippet "(First Case)" between the two equation rows.

Comment: right--edit added from @egreg solution with raisebox