# How to add explanations in the middle of my work? (lyx)

Tags: math-mode, lyx

[image]

Above the equal sign or below, I want to say "newton binom" to explain my transformations. I tried `\underline` and more commands but had no success.

Comment: Can you not use the figure environment with a caption?

Comment: Personally, I would write it on the same line, a little further  on the right.

Comment: have a look -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528218/how-to-write-the-definition-of-each-term-in-an-equation-with-pointing-arrows/528226#528226 -- and -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263480/undersetting-an-arrow-beneath-an-equation -- and -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526435/how-insert-a-text-on-middle-right-of-eqnarray/526439#526439

Comment: In the LyX toolbar there is a button that says "frame decorations". Look at the last two rows (the icons with empty boxes).

Answer (score 1):

I see two main options to achieve what you ask.

1. Use `amsmath`'s `\overset` command to place text above the equal sign.
2. Use `\mathop` to make the equal sign an operator which takes superscripts and subscripts above and below, and use those to place the words.

Here's an example of use of these two options, with a third example where I placed the words higher above the equation using an `array` environment, so it does not mess up with the horizontal alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent
With \verb|\overset|:
\[
(1 + 1)^{2n} \overset{\text{Newton binom}}{=} \sum_{i=1}^{2n} \binom{2n}{i} 1^{2n-i} 1^i
\]
With \verb|\mathop|:
\[
(1 + 1)^{2n} \mathrel{\mathop{=}^{\text{Newton}}_{\text{binom}}} \sum_{i=1}^{2n} \binom{2n}{i} 1^{2n-i} 1^i
\]
With an \verb|array| in \verb|\overset|:
\[
(1 + 1)^{2n} \overset{\mathclap{%
    \begin{array}{c} \scriptstyle\text{Newton binom} \\ \downarrow \end{array}%
}}{=} \sum_{i=1}^{2n} \binom{2n}{i} 1^{2n-i} 1^i
\]
\end{document}
```

However, I must say that none of these options looks very good to me. I think mathematical manipulations should always be explained in complete sentences, from which equations should be a part. I'd go for something like the following.

[image]